# How many files are in a normal Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, debian-based

I searched but can't seem to find the answer anywhere...

For example, in a recent Debian distribution I typed the "ls -R > filelist.txt" command and the total output was over a half a million lines in the text file...   Is this right? It was not my system and I told the owners of it that it seemed like way too many files,  but being a windows guy I wasn't completely sure so I told them I would ask... The Debian version was current.

If someone here could simply pipe out a full file list of their Debian build and let me know how many lines they see please?

Answer (score 0):

While the actual question is offtopic for Stackoverflow I'll answer because computing the number of files is at least a bit related to programming and the way it is done in the question is wrong.

`ls -R` will list not only files, but also directories (multiple times!) and empty lines.

#### Example

Given the following file hierachy

```
.
├── file1
└── subdir
    └── file2
```

The command `ls -R | cat` (`cat` to simulate redirection to a file, which changes the output format) will print

```
.:
file1
subdir

./subdir:
file2
```

#### Alternative Commands

To count the number of files in a system use `find -type f -printf . | wc -c`.

#### Output for me

I have a mostly unused Ubuntu 18.04 server. Some tools like `gcc`, `clang`, and so on were installed. There is only one user having nearly no personal data (running the `find` command in his home directory prints `1274`).

```
$ cd /
$ sudo ls -R | wc -l
303414
$ sudo find -type f -printf . | wc -c
203608
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm still learning my linux command nuances.

So using that command i get :

cd /
ls
bin   content  dev  home  lib32  media  opt   root  sbin  swift  tmp    usr
boot  datalab  etc  lib   lib64  mnt    proc  run   srv   sys    tools  var
$ sudo ls -R | wc -l
532317
$ sudo find -type f -printf . | wc -c
392341                   Still a bit large- I think I will install another and compare the two to see why so many extra files are there.